# PHP/textarea adding random <br /> tags

Tags: php, html

Bit of a strange one, I have a piece of php code that literally takes text out of a database and prints it into a text area.

My problem is that it's converting newline to `<br/>` tags and displaying them in the `textarea`, which I don't want. I have checked the db and there is no `<br />`.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to stop this from happening ?

Comment: Helps if you put the code you have written in the question!

Comment: Provide the code please

Comment: You probably have a rogue `nl2br` call, a function which in my opinion should never have existed... It was added to "solve" a problem that simple CSS (`white-space:pre-wrap`) can already do.

Comment: there are so many ways to jump a <br> tag to your document. cant say exactly without seeing the code.

Comment: you could try to use `<pre><textarea></textarea></pre>`